# How to sum two values of two SeekBars and print it in a textview?

Tags: java, android

I just want to sum two values of two seekbars to sum its value and print it in a text view.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    int x;
    int y;
```

I have created two variables of integers x and y. In the seekBar1 I want to assign the value of seekbar to x. And in the seekBar2 I want to assign the value of seekbar to y.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        SeekBar seekBar1=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.mainSeekBar1);
        SeekBar seekBar2=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.mainSeekBar2);
        final TextView mainTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);
        final TextView totalView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mainTextView2);
        seekBar1.setMax(100);
        seekBar1.setProgress(10);   seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar p1, int progress, boolean p3)
                {   mainTextView.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
                    x = progress;
                }
                //.........
            });
        seekBar2.setMax(20);
        seekBar2.setProgress(10);   seekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar p1, int progress, boolean p3)
                {   mainTextView.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
                    y = progress;
                }
                //...........
            });
        int total=x * y;
        totalView.setText(String.valueOf(total));
    }
```

- here the value of seekBar1 assigned to x
- the value of seekBar2 is assigned to y

I just want to multiply/sum the values of x and y and then print it in textview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not clear what you want:  
Declare the variable sum just like you did with x and y after them:

```
int sum = 0;
```

then:

```
    seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar p1, int progress, boolean p3)
        { 
            mainTextView.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            x=progress;
            sum = x + y;
            totalView.setText(String.valueOf(sum));            }
    });

    seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar p1, int progress, boolean p3)
        {
            mainTextView.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            y=progress;
            sum = x + y;
            totalView.setText(String.valueOf(sum));            }
    });
```

Comment: I need same like this but I need the value of progress assigned to x somewhere else... For example I want to sum two values of two SeekBars to sum them.

Comment: @KhanBoomT20 This is not what you asked. Post another question or edit your current question, rephrase and provide all the necessary code

Comment: This just give me the value of x not y. I want to multiply seekBar1 value with seekBar2 value anywhere.

Comment: I edited my answer. Check it. You can use x and y anywhere in your activity. And what exactly do you want? Add them or multiply them?

Comment: Plz just read the last sentence of my post then answer.

Comment: In my code above you get the sum in the totalView TextView. Where do you want the product of multiplication?

Comment: It just works in seekBar only there can I use it. I want to use it outside the onCreate method.

Comment: The variables x, y and sum can be used throughout your activity.